# Publishing test results to TFS 2018 test cases via REST API

Tags: c#, .net, rest, tfs, automated-tests

**Currently** we are running our automated test using mstest.exe, which then creates a .trx result file. Then, following that, we publish those results using tcm.exe to some test suites/test cases on our TFS server.

We would like to move away from using tcm and publish results from our .trx result file using the TFS REST API.

I have read some of [the documentation on the REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#add-test-results-to-a-test-run) regarding this, but nothing is specific to using the TFS Extended Client classes (such as `TestManagementHttpClient`), it only enumerates the actual URLs to use. It also doesn't give a lot of examples on what parameters it expects.

There is the official [.NET reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.webapi?view=azure-devops-dotnet) for the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.WebApi Namespace which helps a bit, but again it doesn't have any examples/samples to know what parameters each function expects.

The [only example/sample I was able to find](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/77426/need-a-tutorial-how-to-create-test-run-and-post-te.html) was not elaborate enough for me to understand how to apply it in my situation, as I am not familiar enough with the concepts of testpoints/testruns to manipulate the classes that represent them.

I am guessing that a test run has multiple test points (one per test case ran?) representing the result of executing that test case? In which case should I assume I would need to create one test point per test result. If so, how do I know which ID to give it? The sample above hardcodes "3" as its value.

If someone could explain the above sample, and provide a better/more complete one relating to my use case (going from a .trx file, and publishing those results to the test cases matching the linked automation item under a certain test suite), helping me understand how everything correlates together, I would greatly appreciate.

Thank you.

Comment: Which version of tfs?  Are you running the test through a build pipeline?  Running from a pipeline on the new versions of tfs has test publishing steps or I believe will just do it for you if you use the test task.

Comment: A Test run can contain multiple test cases. Each test case can have 1 or more Test Points. Each test point represents a different time the testcase was executed. Each execution can come from a different Test Configuration or a different Test Environment or anything else that results in a new result for the same testcase.

Comment: @Matt We are currently using TFS 2018.3, but are not using the build pipeline. All automated tests are started manually by a "homemade" framework which calls MSTest.exe on a bunch of test binaries/categories.

Comment: You could create a "fake build" and then use the standard trx publishing options. The only thing you need is an empty build record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to answer my own question based on the example/sample I have linked in my question:

1. You need to get the test configuration you want using `TestManagementHttpClient.GetTestConfigurationsAsync()`
2. Then you would want to fetch all test points for that test case/test configuration combination using `TestManagementHttpClient.GetPointsAsync()`
3. You then need to create a test run. This is done by declaring a new `RunCreateModel` object by **at least** specifying the test points IDs you have previously fetched. There is plenty of parameters you might want to fill in as well (`buildId`, `isAutomated`, etc). You then need to call `TestManagementHttpClient.CreateTestRunAsync()` to actually create it.
4. Step 3 actually created empty test results under the test run, for each test point you have specified when you created it. You need to fetch them using `TestManagementHttpClient.GetTestResultsAsync()` and modify the `Outcome` property on them, using the `TestCaseResult.TestCase.Id` property to know which result is for which test case. You also might want to fill in other properties, such as `State`, etc. Again, you need to push those modifications to TFS using `TestManagementHttpClient.UpdateTestResultsAsync()`
5. Last step is to set your test run as completed by creating a `RunUpdateModel` object with `state = "Completed"` and then calling `TestManagementHttpClient.UpdateTestRunAsync()`

Here is the function I ended up writing that does all that, written in F#:

```
// A test point is a pairing of a test case with a test configuration
let createTestRun (httpClient:TestManagementHttpClient) (testRunName:string) (teamProjectName:string) (testPlanId:int) (testSuiteId:int) (testCaseIdsAndResults:seq<(int * string)>) (buildId:int) (cancellationToken:CancellationToken) = async {
    let testPlanIdString = testPlanId.ToString()
    let plan = new ShallowReference(testPlanIdString)

    let! testConfigurations = httpClient.GetTestConfigurationsAsync(teamProjectName, cancellationToken = cancellationToken) |> Async.AwaitTask
    let defaultTestConfiguration = testConfigurations |> Seq.find (fun c -> c.IsDefault) // TODO: We only use the default configuration for now. Do we always want this?

    let rec getTestPoints (testIdsAndResults:(int * string) list) (testPoints:TestPoint[]) = async {
        match testIdsAndResults with
        | (testId, _)::rest ->
            let! fetchedTestPoints = httpClient.GetPointsAsync(teamProjectName, testPlanId, testSuiteId, testCaseId = testId.ToString(), cancellationToken = cancellationToken) |> Async.AwaitTask
            let testPoint = fetchedTestPoints |> Seq.find (fun p -> p.Configuration.Id = defaultTestConfiguration.Id.ToString())
            let newTestPointsList = Array.append testPoints [|testPoint|]
            return! getTestPoints rest newTestPointsList
        | _ ->
            return testPoints
    }
    let! testPoints = getTestPoints (List.ofSeq testCaseIdsAndResults) Array.empty
    let testPointIds = testPoints |> Array.map (fun p -> p.Id)

    let runCreateModel = new RunCreateModel(name = testRunName, plan = plan, buildId = buildId, isAutomated = new Nullable<bool>(true), pointIds = testPointIds)
    let! testRun = httpClient.CreateTestRunAsync(runCreateModel, teamProjectName, cancellationToken = cancellationToken) |> Async.AwaitTask
    let! emptyResults = httpClient.GetTestResultsAsync(project = teamProjectName, runId = testRun.Id, outcomes = new List<TestOutcome>(), cancellationToken = cancellationToken) |> Async.AwaitTask

    let rec createCaseResults (testIdsAndResults:(int * string) list) (results:TestCaseResult[]) = async {
        match testIdsAndResults with
        | (testId, testResult)::rest ->
            let caseResult = emptyResults |> Seq.find (fun r -> r.TestCase.Id = testId.ToString())
            caseResult.State <- "Completed"
            caseResult.Outcome <- testResult // "passed", "failed", "never run", "not applicable"
            let newResultsList = Array.append results [|caseResult|]
            return! createCaseResults rest newResultsList
        | _ ->
            return results
    }
    let! results = createCaseResults (List.ofSeq testCaseIdsAndResults) Array.empty
    let! _ = httpClient.UpdateTestResultsAsync(results, teamProjectName, testRun.Id, cancellationToken = cancellationToken) |> Async.AwaitTask

    let runmodel = new RunUpdateModel(state = "Completed");
    let! _ = httpClient.UpdateTestRunAsync(runmodel, teamProjectName, testRun.Id, cancellationToken = cancellationToken) |> Async.AwaitTask

    ()
}
```